# What different is there between Snapshot and backup hyper-v vps?

Tags: hosting

What different is there between Snapshot  hyper-v vps  and backup hyper-v vps ? can I restore my vps from a Snapshot ?

Comment: And a staff alway tell me  "Snapshot is always on same server and it'll be lost in case of HDD crash, it is not a replacement of backups". Right?

Answer (score 0):

Hyper-V snapshots are used to revert your server to a previous point in time (e.g. prior to software install or application of updates).  That way, you can recover quickly in case changes being made cause a failure.  BUT, snapshots are stored with the hyper-v guest itself and can't be used to recover a server should the host fail.  That's why you still need to make regular backups (either within the guest or via vhd backup).

Comment: Mmore exactly: It is a good idea to put up a snapshot before upgrading software configuration. Something does not work - EASY and FAST to rollback. Backups are offsite, longer term and follow a schedule. And should be on DEFINITELY another system, isolated and possibly offsite.

Answer (score 0):

Hyper V Snapshot also known as Checkpoint (System Center Virtual Machine Manager)is manually created by the user to allow you to roll back the entire machine to the past point in time.

While It is a live Snapshot that is made in backup time which makes sure that all the data has been flushed and ready to backup. Snapshot notifies windows to flush all data so that no disk I/O is in memory. It then begins a snapshot process. Once the snapshot is taken, I/O is resumed.